# What is the missing metric to this graph: days/week exercised -vs ______?

Tags: exercise

I was shown this graph in a college PE class on general fitness.  I remember the general shape, and that the bottom metric was in reference to the number of days per week that a person exercised.  The general point was that if you worked out 1-2 days per week you saw some but little benefit.  If you exercised 3-4 days per week, there were dramatic increases.  5 days still got a measurable increase,  but 6-7 days were pretty much a waste of "efficient" time.  Can you tell me where this came from, what the metric on the left side is, and if it still holds true with today's knowledge.
[image]

Comment: Data above is fictitious and is made-up in an attempt to recreate the one I saw.

Comment: +1 Seems like a question I wouldn't mind seeing the answer to :).

Comment: argh. I know I've seen this somewhere as well.

Comment: I suppose I'll have to leave this question unanswered.  CanESER provided a very nice current alternative so I granted a +1, but it did not answer this question.

Answer (score 1):

It is AAEI(Accumulated Activity Effective Index)

[image]

[You can see here](http://www.researchprotocols.org/2015/1/e5/)

Regards...

Comment: Why don't you add some text on what the index means?

Comment: I think its more clear now ;) @FredrikD Thanks for your suggestion

Comment: I could be wrong, but, I think FredrikD meant a generic explanation rather than a copy of the formula from the web page.

Comment: This is the right concept.  But figure 3 in the referenced article shows large gains on day 1.  The graph I saw showed the most gains on day 4, next best was day 3, third best on day 5. With moderate gains on days 2 and 6.  Looks like we are on the right track though.  Also, the article referenced was published on Jan. 6 2015 and I saw this data in 1996-7.  Perhaps it has been superseded?

Comment: In my opinion there is so much difference between person who doesn't train and train once a week. So decreasingly growing seems more logical for me. @Jammin4CO

Comment: @Jammin4CO - I agree. While the chart is similar and probably comes from the same type of approach, this is not the chart you are referring to. I've also seen it in my studies somewhere, which would originally put it in the early 1990's.

Comment: @CanESER-I suppose this would be a tangent and thus a different question to determine the benefit of training 1 day per week versus none at all.  Thank you for your insight, but this is not the answer to the question asked.